# Plot stacked bar chart from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have dataframe:

`payout_df.head(10)`

[image]

What would be the easiest, smartest and fastest way to replicate the following excel plot?

[image]

I've tried different approaches, but couldn't get everything into place.

Thanks

Comment: Is the issue with the stacked bar chart, or the extra labeling and axis formatting?

Comment: @ALollz with the chart itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want a stacked bar chart, then one way is to use a loop to plot each column in the dataframe and just keep track of the cumulative sum, which you then pass as the `bottom` argument of `pyplot.bar`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# If it's not already a datetime
payout_df['payout'] = pd.to_datetime(payout_df.payout)

cumval=0
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
for col in payout_df.columns[~payout_df.columns.isin(['payout'])]:
    plt.bar(payout_df.payout, payout_df[col], bottom=cumval, label=col)
    cumval = cumval+payout_df[col]

_ = plt.xticks(rotation=30)
_ = plt.legend(fontsize=18)
```

[image]

Comment: I get this `TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')`

Comment: and if I don't use conversion `to_datetime`
 I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'float'` @ALollz

Comment: @user40  Not sure. I just updated the example since I realized you're `df` was called `payout_df`. It seems like somehow you were trying to combine datetime and float columns, which won't work and shouldn't be happening

Comment: small suggestion, change import line to "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt", if not code doesn't compile :-)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the lack of data, I think the following code will produce the desired graph

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.payout = pd.to_datetime(df.payout)

grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='payout', freq='M')).sum()
grouped.plot(x=grouped.index.year, kind='bar', stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

I don't know how to reproduce this fancy x-axis style. Also, your `payout` column must be a datetime, otherwise [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) won't work ([available frequencies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)).

Comment: `grouped.plot(x=grouped.index.strftime('%B'), kind='bar', stacked=True)`. You can check the options for **strftime** [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). You should also use `plt.xticks(rotation=45)` for better visualization.